# I get 504 Gateway Time-out when call api from postman or front in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

I get 504 Gateway Time-out when call api from postman or front.
but when call api locally everything is ok.

I use :

```
webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
          .UseKestrel(o => { o.Limits.RequestHeadersTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); })
          .UseKestrel(o => { o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); });
```

Comment: How do you call the API locally?

Comment: I call api with postman. this is my api :[HttpGet("report/{appId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport([FromRoute] string appId){}

Comment: `when call api locally everything is ok.` what do you mean be this?

Comment: I mean when I publish project on Aws , I have problem. but when I locally by https:5001Run this api, I get this error.